# Implementing Python Multiprocessing with Pools

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to get some experience with multithreading in Python. I'm using a game to do it, but I'm running into strange synchronization issues which create very odd bugs in my game. What follows is what I feel is the relevant code (the project is 500 lines, didn't want to overload with all of it)

I have a game object which controls aspects of the UI and passing your commands to the player object. My plan was to create the pool in main, and pass the pool into the processEvents() methods for my player/computer to use for large jobs.

```
import sys
from Player import Player
from AI import AI
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

class RTSGame(object):
    def processEvents(self):
        self.player.processEvents(self.ai.getShips(), pool)
        self.ai.processEvents(self.player.getUnits(), pool)
    #end processEvents

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = RTSGame()
    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
    game.main()
```

Eventually, the pool object ends up here:

```
def findTarget(self, targets, pool):
    '''
    Returns the target best meeting the search criteria.
    Currently just does closest. Will add criteria for strongest, weakest, or type.
    '''
    results = pool.map(findTargetHelper, map(lambda target: (self, target), targets))
    shortest = min(results)
    if shortest[0] < self.attackinfo.getRange():
        return shortest[1] #return the ship at shortest distance
    else:
        return None #return nothing
    ''' Old Code
    shortest = self.attackinfo.getRange() #You must be within the range of your weapons
    shortestTarget = None
    distfunc = self.getDistance
    for target in targets:
        dist = distfunc(self.position, target.getPosition())
        if dist < shortest:
            shortest = dist
            shortestTarget = target

    return shortestTarget
    '''
#end findTarget()

def findTargetHelper(target): #target[0] is assumed to be the one searching for a target
    return (target[0].getDistance(target[0].getPosition(), target[1].getPosition()), target[1])
```

Please note that the findTargetHelper() is not a method of this object (to get around the pickleing problem). When using my old code it runs fine but can take a bit of time with a large amount of objects.

My problems are strange. It seems that nothing is being updated when the objects are being modified (through taking damage through attacks for example).

I think I'm missing something crucial in my code to make this work. And I want this to work, as I have other areas I could use this in (drawing is cpu intensive, for example).

Edit: I've been doing lots of research trying to figure this out. My research has been unsuccessful. I'd appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: > My problems are strange. It seems that nothing is being updated when the objects are being modified (through taking damage through attacks for example).

Comment: Are you trying to modify instances from main process inside pool workers?

Comment: What is seen in the code above is all I'm doing with the pool. It isn't used anywhere else, it just gets passed as a parameter to other objects and ends up in this method. I can add more detail, if you need it.

Comment: I can't find any "object modification" in this snippet and you are writing that "nothing is being updated when the objects are being modified".
What does it mean "synchronization issue"?

In general I think that you should use different approach to speed up `collision detection` or `nearest neighbour` search. I can suggest (as I've used them in practice) k-d trees.

Comment: Yes all the object modifications are not included in the snippet. Here is a video representing what's happening: http://youtu.be/ZYQXXLwghBo. The right screen is the one with the pool. It isn't destroying the ships properly, and the missiles don't follow. The left is working as intended. I've thought about maintaining a tree of all the objects, but if all the objects move, then I'm doing O(n) updates that each take O(log n) time. I don't necessarily want this either.

Comment: paluh, I am implementing a K-D tree to do the nearest neighbor search, but I'm running into issues with my search. Do you have some reference material that explains well the algorithm to do the search? I'm getting stuck with colliding the planes with the search radius.

Comment: Unfortunately I've implemented k-d tree inside my ray tracer (written in C) at university and I don't have/remember related materials (I've also lost my code - there was no github at that time ;-))... Have you checked if there are any Python libraries which you can use directly? Or do you want to implement k-d tree for fun/training?

Comment: I am doing this as a learning opportunity. I actually figured out my implementation; its working now. However; a KD tree doesn't seem to work well for objects that move every frame. I was going to look at a Quadtree instead, unless you had a suggestion. At this rate, rebuilding the KD tree every frame is going to end up being slower than my brute force approach.

Comment: > However; a KD tree doesn't seem to work well for objects that move every frame.
Good point. I've used them only for static scene rendering, so I'm not sure if there is any way to optimze k-d tree for managing moving objects... I'm going to look at Quadtree too (just for fun) ;-)